# Angular JS displaying a specific ng-grid in a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-grid

Friends, i have a tree that is dynamically created from JSON.  It also creates the grids that i want for a particular element on the tree and hides them all.  Then i have a ng-click that shows it.  My problem is that it shows ALL of them instead of the one that i want.  For example, if user clicks on the header in 'Record 1' it should display the first grid and so on and so on.   [Here is my JSBin](http://jsbin.com/dodiyi/166/edit?html,js,output).

My HTML looks like this.  Please see my JSBin for JavaScript file:

```
 <body ng-controller="AbnTestController" style="margin:20px">
               <button ng-click="try_changing_the_tree_data()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Submit File</button>      
           <p>
            <table width="100%" style="height: 100%;" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="0">
               <tr>
                  <!-- ============ LEFT COLUMN (TREE) ============== -->
                  <td width="250px" style="vertical-align:top" bgcolor="whitesmoke">
                     <div style="width:250px;background:whitesmoke;border:1px solid lightgray;border-radius:5px;">
                        <abn-tree ng-click="visible.grid = true" tree-data="my_data" tree-control="my_tree" on-select="my_tree_handler(branch)" expand-level="2"></abn-tree>
                     </div>
                  </td>
                  <!-- ============ RIGHT COLUMN (CONTENT) ============== -->
                  <td width="80%" valign="top" bgcolor="#d2d8c7">

                    <div style="vertical-align:top;">
                        <div ng-repeat="rule in rules">
                           <div ng-show="visible.grid == true"  class="gridStyle" ng-grid="rule.grid" ></div>

                        </div>

                        <div id="results"></div>
                     </div>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
            </p>
   </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/muxaxi/edit?js,output)

HTML (diff):

```
<div ng-repeat="rule in rules">
  <div 
    ng-show="rulesMap[rule.uid] == 'isVisible'" 
    class="gridStyle" 
    ng-grid="rule.grid"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript remove calls to createGrids and:

```
$scope.my_tree_handler = function(branch) {
  createGridsFromBranch(branch);
};

/*Function that builds the grid*/
$scope.rulesMap = {};
$scope.rules = [];
createGridsFromBranch = function(branch) {
  var gridUid = 'g_'+branch.uid;
  for(var i in $scope.rulesMap) {
    $scope.rulesMap[i] = 'notVisible';
  }
  if($scope.rulesMap[gridUid]) {
    $scope.rulesMap[gridUid] = 'isVisible';
    return;
  }
  $scope.rulesMap[gridUid] = 'isVisible';
  $scope.rules.push({
    uid: gridUid,
    grid: {
      ...
    }
  });
```

Comment: Yeah, i get that.  But my problem is as soon as the user changes over to another to another tree element, like record 2, then goes back, the changes they did in the grid are gone.  So i figure why not just load them all and hide them, then depending on which one they clicked i would just display it.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I'll try to add a link to a working JSBin soon.

Comment: I've been at this for a bit now.  I can't wait to see what you come up with.

Comment: @Goat I've added a link to the answer. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Sorry but i don't see no link.  The suspense is killing me.